# Varchar(100) takes more space than char(100) on variable length data

Tags: sql-server, char, varchar

I am on a quest to understand the different char datatypes in SQL Server. I have a test column `Address` with 100.000 records of type `char(100)`. The data distribution in the column is uniform, which means each character length between 1-100 is represented exactly 1000 times. I then ran the following script, expecting to see a decrease in storage space used:

```
exec sp_spaceused N'AddressTable' -- Data size: 59.920 KB

alter table dbo.AddressTable
alter column [Address] varchar(100)

alter table dbo.AddressTable REBUILD

exec sp_spaceused N'AddressTable' -- Data size: 61.848 KB
```

but as you can see, varchar(100) actually takes up more space than char(100). How is that possible, given that the data entries vary so much in size?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you create a new table, and then insert your data into it, instead of using ALTER TABLE?

Alternatively, if your table has a clustered index (no DDL so we don't know) try this:

```
ALTER INDEX ClusteredIndexName ON YourTable REBUILD
```

Comment: While creating a new table and inserting the data into it did not change anything, it did lead me towards the answer. After changing the column type, I can use trim([Address]) to remove the extra padding on the char type. Rebuilding the table after this operation reduces the space needed, as expected. Thanks for your comment.